# What are the differences between until now and so far?

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between `Until now` and `So far`?

Please explain to me what the difference is between them.

Comment: 'So far' certainly has non-temporal usages that 'until now' doesn't: _He will only be pushed so far. It's so far to the nearest star after the Sun that man will never reach it. So far, so good._

Comment: @nima_persian, those two phrases can often be used interchangeably. It would be helpful if you could provide an example sentence or two so we can understand the context you're thinking about.

Comment: When they are used interchangeably, "until now" must go *after* the thing that it refers to; "so far" can be before or after it.  ("Alice has been responsible so far", "Alice has been responsible until now", "So far Alice has been responsible", but \*"Until now Alice has been responsible").  To my ear, "until now" also weakly suggests that something has changed, whereas "so far" has no such implication at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference, as usual, is between the metaphor involved, if there is one.

*Until* is one of the very few words in English that actually refers to time duration
(others include *when, while, now, then, during, duration,* and *endure*).
All the other ways we refer to time, like *[spend time](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/TIM.pdf)*, are metaphorical.

The metaphor involved in *so far* (as in *up to now* and *up to the present moment*)
is the [`Time Passing Is Motion` metaphor theme](https://books.google.com/books?id=zlsm5XpRGYMC&pg=PA37&lpg=PA37&dq=time+passing+is+motion+metaphor).

There are two versions of this, depending on viewpoint. As Kövecses labels them,

1. TIME PASSING IS AN OBSERVER'S MOTION OVER A LANDSCAPE:
   i.e, the observer is in motion along a path while passing stationary temporal events
   (*Up to now* is licensed by this version)
2. TIME PASSING IS MOTION OF AN OBJECT
   i.e, the observer is stationary while moving temporal events pass by

Both are cognitive nonsense, of course, and they're even contradictory,
but that's normal for metaphors, which are theories invented by four-year-olds;
they all start out as nonsense in the first place, and continue by violating
the first premise of logic:

> A proposition cannot be both true and false.

In using *up to now*, the speaker is conjuring up the image of observing temporal events while moving up (i.e, along) a path in a landscape, and is positing some proposition of all the events that have been observed along the path (from some indefinite starting point). Time is strictly metaphoric here.

With *until now*, however, no metaphor is used; this is a direct reference to perceived duration.

Answer (score 4):

I would say that "until now" suggests that the condition you are about to describe is at an end, "So far" suggests that the condition is still ongoing.

"Until now, no all-woman team has won the tournament", means that an all-woman tournament just won for the first time ever.

"So far, no all-woman team has won the tournament" suggests that that event (the all-woman team winning) has not happened.

Comment: I agree with this logic explanation!